# How to exclude any other words in fulltext SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, full-text-search

I need to find records which have all the given words in any order/combo, but not have any other words, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`field`) AGAINST('+word1 +word2 +word3 +word4' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This query does not exclude words not listed.

Excluding words with minus, like `-word5 -word6` is not the case because there is no possibility to predict which words could be present in a sentence.

Is it possible to exclude all the words not present in a query?

Data examples. My database includes millions of trivial names of species (plants, animals, etc.) in languages which have no strict word order. For example, Ukrainian. I have a single record for each species, but user input could be any combination of words like:

```
чорна сосна
сосна чорна

європейська сосна
сосна європейська

європейська чорна сосна
сосна чорна європейська
чорна європейська сосна
чорна сосна європейська

чорна кримська сосна
сосна кримська чорна
кримська чорна сосна
чорна сосна кримська

чорна кримська європейська сосна
кримська європейська чорна сосна
чорна європейська кримська сосна
сосна європейська кримська чорна
сосна чорна європейська кримська
сосна чорна кримська європейська
```

Even more than 4-words combo is possible. All these blocks is different species and it is important to get only one record.

Comment: Is this really natural language text? It seems like a strange operation on normal text, sounds more like something that would be done on a list of keywords. And in that case, you should normalize your data rather than putting it in free-format text.

Comment: agree with Barmar; show some example data to help us understand the problem

Comment: @Barmar and ysth, thank you for your replies! I've added some examples in the post.

Comment: @ysth An example data is in the post already. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like lists of keywords to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that there is nothing additional in the field by removing the matching words and spaces and seeing that there's nothing left:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE MATCH (`field`) AGAINST('+word1 +word2 +word3 +word4' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND 0 = CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'word1',''),'word2',''),'word3',''),'word4',''),' ',''))
```

If you have punctuation or other non-word characters besides spaces, you may also need to remove those, or change the removing spaces and length test with a regex looking if there are any word characters remaining.